# Passing a function and its argument(s) as parameters of a function

Tags: powershell, functional-programming

I want to write a function which accepts a function and its argument(s).

I can run a function within a function when I'm hardcoding it, but that's not what I need. Powershell supports first class functions so this should be possible.

This works:

```
function pass_arg{
    param([string] $arg)
    Write-Host "pass_arg ran with: $arg"
}

function pass_runner{
    param([string] $arg)
    pass_arg $arg
}

pass_runner "some string argument."
```

This doesn't:

```
function func_w_arg{
    param([string] $arg)
    Write-Host "func_w_arg ran with: $arg"
}

function runner_w_func{
    param($func, [string] $arg)
    #Runner stuff...
    func $arg
}
runner_w_func func_w_arg "some string argument"
```

Error:

```
func : The term 'func' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or
operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the
path is correct and try again
```

So, the error occurs in the runner function's namespace when I try to use the

```
$func
```

argument as a callable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two options:

1. Pass the name of a command to the call operator `&`, or
2. Pass a `[scriptblock]` as a parameterized arguments:

### 1. passing a command name:

```
function func_w_arg{
    param([string] $arg)
    Write-Host "func_w_arg ran with: $arg"
}

function runner_w_func{
    param([string]$func, [string] $arg)
    #Runner stuff...
    & $func $arg
}

runner_w_func func_w_arg "some string argument"
```

### 2. passing a `[scriptblock]`:

```
function func_w_arg{
    param([string] $arg)
    Write-Host "func_w_arg ran with: $arg"
}

function runner_w_func{
    param([scriptblock]$func, [string] $arg)
    #Runner stuff...
    & $func $arg
}

runner_w_func func_w_arg "some string argument"
```

As you can see, the call operator accepts both, so we might as well combine them:

```
function Invoke-Function {
    param(
        [ValidateScript({$_ -is [string] -or $_ -is [scriptblock]})]
        [object]$func,
        [string] $arg
    )

    & $func $arg
}
```

---

### Handling arguments

Although, what if you have multiple arguments?

Fix that by accepting either an array for the argument list, or a dictionary is you want named parameter binding for the inner function:

```
function Invoke-Function {
    param(
        [ValidateScript({$_ -is [string] -or $_ -is [scriptblock]})]
        [object]$func,
        [array]$ArgumentList,
        [System.Collections.IDictionary]$NamedArguments
    )

    if($PSBoundParameters.ContainsKey('ArgumentList')){
        return & $func $ArgumentList @NamedArguments
    }

    return & $func @NamedArguments
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your timely and comprehensive response. I've managed to get it working using version 1. The version 2, however throws an error: Cannot convert the
"func_w_arg" value of type "System.String" to type "System.Management.Automation.ScriptBlock".

Comment: Regarding example 1, I'm guessing the [string] in param is type hinting because it also works without [string]. But shouldn't that throw an error if any non string types are passed as an argument(in this case a function object)?

Comment: @PersonPr7 I think you might not have defined the second version of the `Invoke-Function` properly, nothing in it attempts a conversion to `[scriptblock]`. WRT `[string]`, PowerShell will attempt to convert any non-`[string]` input value to a string - which is never not possible, so it won't fail unless the resulting string is empty :)

Comment: "PowerShell will attempt to convert any non-[string] input value to a string" Does that make it a weakly typed language?

Comment: @PersonPr7 Quite the contrary. It makes PowerShell *optionally strongly-typed*. If you declare a typed parameter (like in my examples) or apply a type cast to the left-hand side of an assignment, your variables become strongly typed. PowerShell then implicitly adds some additional logic to faciliate type conversion during parameter binding.